# Python, can't assert if method called from another class

Tags: python, mocking, patch, assert

I have the following code in Python:

```
class A():
    def doSomething(self, bClass):
        print(bClass.theThing)

class B():
    def __init__(self, theThing):
        self.theThing = theThing

def foo():
    a = A()
    b = B("that thing")
    a.doSomething(b)
```

I have those classes and the function foo() stored in testing.py and I want to test that the A's method was called with:

```
import testing, unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TheTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
            with patch('testing.A.doSomething') as do:
                testing.foo()
                do.assert_any_call()
```

But I always get 'doSomething() call not found'. I would be happier if I could understand why but at this point anything is welcome

Comment: what happens if you create a blank file named `__init__.py` in the same directory? To understand how namespace packages and importing works please see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)

Comment: Did this help with your problem, George? If so I can add a detailed answer to help others that may be reading this looking for a solution.

Comment: Nope, I still can't understand why this is happening

Comment: the `assert_any_call()` is attempting to parse `testing.A.doSomething` however an argument hasn't been included as `doSomething` expects a `bClass`. Did you perhaps mean to use `assert_called_with(<insert a class>)?`

Comment: That is what I did initially but it failed the same way 'call not found'. Should I mock class B and use it as argument in assert_called_with( ) ?

Comment: The mock will likely fail as you have created a new instance of `bClass`, unless this is what you were attempting to reproduce with your unit test?

Comment: I want to know if method of class A() was called with an instance of class B. That's why I after a point of testing and failing I went to assert_any_calls since I couldn't figure out how to test for assert_called_with(<class B>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours I started figuring this out.
Like jwjhdev said `assert_called_with()` expects something and in my case a class but so does `assert_any_call()`. For some reason I was thinking `assert_any_call()` would just work but what I was thinking was `assert_called()` which just works without arguments. In the end I figured it out by adding a `return b` to the `foo()` function and:

```
def foo():
    a = A()
    b = B("that thing")
    a.doSomething(b)
    return b
```

```
class TheTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
            with patch('testing.A.doSomething') as do:
                b = testing.foo()
                do.assert_any_call(b)
```